# The parenthesis problem from above in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, amsmath, braces

The parenthesis sign is too long in the part you see in the delta sign. I couldn't do it as a fixed parenthesis. We used `\bigl` but it doesn't work. We used `\underbrace` and we couldn't reach the result. The only problem is that I want to put a parenthesis that will be complete in the square under the expression (< delta).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-3) grid (5,5);
\draw[thick] (-3,-4) -- (-3,5.5);
\draw[thick] (-6,1) -- (6.5,1);
\draw (-4,5) node[font = {\Huge}, black]{$M$};
\draw (-4,-2) node[font = {\Huge}, black]{$M$};
\draw (-2,1) node[below left, font = {\Huge}, black]{$a$};
\draw (5,1) node[below right, font = {\Huge}, black]{$b$};
\draw (5,5) node[below right, font = {\Huge}, black]{$\bigl\{\lt\Tilde{\epsilon}$};
\draw (-2,6) node[below right, font = {\Huge}, black]{$\lt \delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Shouldn't the braces be mirrored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the `decorations` library and draw the braces using Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, font={\Huge}]
    \draw[step=1cm, gray, very thin] (-2,-3) grid (5,5);
    \draw (-3,-4) -- (-3,5.5);
    \draw (-6,1) -- (6.5,1);
    \node at (-4,5) {$M$};
    \node at (-4,-2) {$M$};
    \node[below left] at (-2,1) {$a$};
    \node[below right] at (5,1) {$b$};
    \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace}] ([xshift=5pt]5,5) -- ([xshift=5pt]5,4)
        node[midway, right=5pt, anchor=west]{$< \tilde{\epsilon}$};
    \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace}] ([yshift=5pt]-2,5) -- ([yshift=5pt]0,5)
        node[midway, above=5pt, anchor=south]{$< \delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]